# Messed up OpenBox installation

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, openbox

I was using Gnome as is it in 18.04. I installed the following -

```
openbox
obconf
obmenu
openbox-menu
tint2
arandr
```

I am using a laptop with an external monitor connected through the HDMI port. Internally, the HDMI port comes out directly from the Nvidia GPU, instead of the Intel one, so anything on the external monitor is rendered by the discrete GPU. When I switched to Openbox I had the following problems -

1. No display on the laptop screen, only on the external display. arandr didn't show the primary screen.
2. The right-click menu never disappeared, new menus overlapped on one another.
3. Dragging open windows around left a shadow behind.

All this was just at boot, I haven't edited ay config/dotfiles or anything.

In the attached image you can see that -

- arandr has only one display
- the submenu of system has overlapped the one of the development section, and the development section has not disappeared
- window shadow when arandr window has been dragged around
- there are many other right menus behind the shadows, they never disappear.

[image]